# ruby user.profile link_to

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make the user profile a link on my project.

originally, my code would be:

```
<%= gig.user.profile %>
```

which would just display the user profile name.

I want to set a link to but all i can get to work is:

```
<%= link_to "user", gig.user.profile %>
```

It links correctly to the user profile page but obviously does not display the correct user profile name.

I have also tried:

```
<%= link_to user.profile_name(id: gig.user.profile_name) %>
```

but it just throws an error.  any ideas?

Comment: `link_to gig.user.profile_name, gig.user.profile`, assuming `profile_name` is the name you want to display and `profile` is an ActiveRecord object.

Comment: tried that, i still get an: undefined method `profile_name' for #<User:0x007fcfb9478818>

Comment: "assuming `profile_name` is the name you want to display". Clearly, it's not. You'll need to give more detail about your User class if you want an answer, though I'd bet that `profile.name` is what you actually want.

Comment: hah, not sure why but that comment just answered my question.

Comment: `profile.name` is _very_ different from `profile_name`. One's asking for the `name` attribute of `profile`, the other is looking for a variable called `profile_name`.

Comment: ahh, makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  my User Class stated that my profile_name was actually just profile. Correct code is as follows:

```
<%= link_to gig.user.profile, gig.user.profile %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you looking like,

```
<%= link_to gig.user.profile.name, gig.user.profile %>
```

Assuming `profile` have `name` attribute.

Comment: yeah, i did not have the name attribute.  thanks a lot though mr. snow.